# Отправка данных на email

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, я пока что плохо разбираюсь в php. Кто может помогите пожалуйста с кодом для обработки. Есть такая вот форма на сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот её код html:

```
<h3>Заполните форму, мы вам обязательно ответим:</h3>
<form action="post.php">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Имя</label>
    <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Ваш контактный e-mail или телефон</label>
    <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш контактный e-mail или телефон" type="email">
  </div>    

  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="message" class="sr-only">Ваше сообщение</label>
    <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group ">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Отправить" type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Попытался сам написать код php, но он не работает, кто может напишите пожалуйста код, чтобы после заполнения формы и нажатия на "отправить", он отправлялся на нужный email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, добавьте атрибуты `name` к каждому из `input` и `textarea`, чтобы мы могли получить их через POST-запрос:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Имя</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Ваш контактный e-mail или телефон</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш контактный e-mail или телефон" type="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="sr-only">Ваше сообщение</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Отправить" type="submit" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Чтобы отправить сообщение на почту, воспользуйтесь функцией **[`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php):**

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * post.php file
 *
 */

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $email = 'email@email.com'; // адрес, куда будет отправляться письмо

    $from = "От: " . $_POST['name'] . ", " . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";
    $message = $from . "Сообщение: <br>" . $_POST['message'];

    if(mail($email, 'Заголовок', $message)) {
        echo 'Успешно отправлено';
    } else {
        echo 'Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения';
    }
}
```

Comment: ?> зачем внизу поставили ведь в psr 2 это ошибка

Comment: а как указать на какую почту отправить сообщение? не вижу это в самом коде

Comment: @Sambl так переменная `$email` указывает на почту, на которую будет отправлено сообщение. Если вам нужно, чтобы ваше сообщение отправлялось на отдельную почту, измените `mail('pochta@pochta.ru', $name, $message);`

Comment: @Sambl обновил ответ, проверяйте.